# Does TEXT datatype will limit the length ?

Tags: android, mysql, text, sqldatatypes

I'm using `TEXT` datatype in `MySQL`. But when I check the column, I only see `fndjdjjj jdjejcdjj sekifkj sjkedkjfj sjekkcjej jwj...`. After jwj, it suppose to have another text, but I get ...Why would this happened ? I thought TEXT can have unlimited size ?

I'm using android , and connecting with MySQL PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LONGTEXT.

Following are the limits

```
          Type | Maximum length
    -----------+-------------------------------------
      TINYTEXT |           255 (2 8−1) bytes
          TEXT |        65,535 (216−1) bytes = 64 KiB
    MEDIUMTEXT |    16,777,215 (224−1) bytes = 16 MiB
      LONGTEXT | 4,294,967,295 (232−1) bytes =  4 GiB
```

Comment: If I already have data inside MySQL. After change to LONGTEXT, will my data in the column get deleted?

Comment: Inside your MySQL if existing field is TEXT then you would have data which are permitted till its length only. If you want to change, you should change the tableStructure where your data may be impacted. Think of backup & migrate it to updated structure

Comment: I have changed to LongText, then I insert text again, the text still limited

Comment: Check if trying to insert unicode text. And your table's charset is set to latin1. 
Change your table charset to utf-8.

ALTER TABLE tablename {.....} CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;  More info http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 1):

`TINYTEXT` is limited to 255 *bytes*.  Note the truncation during insert.  Note that the data is intact after the `ALTER`.  Note that I used `MODIFY`, not `CONVERT TO`.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE so35474581 ( t TINYTEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.24 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO so35474581 (t) SELECT repeat('x', 444);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.04 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 't' at row 1 |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT LENGTH(t), CHAR_LENGTH(t) FROM so35474581;
+-----------+----------------+
| LENGTH(t) | CHAR_LENGTH(t) |
+-----------+----------------+
|       255 |            255 |
+-----------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE so35474581 MODIFY t LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET latin1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.31 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT LENGTH(t), CHAR_LENGTH(t) FROM so35474581;
+-----------+----------------+
| LENGTH(t) | CHAR_LENGTH(t) |
+-----------+----------------+
|       255 |            255 |
+-----------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The `CONVERT TO` mentioned has to do with changing character sets.

When inserting anything over a few MB, you may have trouble with packet_size or other settings.